# X11 graphics programming Font

Tags: c++, x11, embedded-linux

I am developing User Interface software using X11 programming.(I am not used QT, Widget, GTk).In that i want to increase font size using font property function. How can i use XFontProp function? Is there any other method to increase font size using X windows? If is it possible give me a sample?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the old-fashioned now-deprecated server-side font rendering method, you cannot *change* the font size, you need to *load* the correctly-sized fond. Use `XLoadFont` and/or `XLoadQueryFont` for this. Use the `Font` you get in your `GC`.

To see what the string parameter looks like, type `xlsfonts` on your computer, or use `xfontsel` GUI utility.

Note that any given X server may lack fonts you want to use. There are only few mandatory fonts including `fixed` and I forgot what else.

If you want to use the fashionable modern client-side font rendering (what most programss written today are using) you have to use one of the toolkits, or Xft2 or Cairo libraries.